# Using localized text in UILabel in Interface builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to use the localized version of a string directly in the interface builder? Or do I need to obtain a reference to each label etc on the screen and then manually use `NSLocalizedString(...);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Utilities panel, in the File Inspector you will find the Localization section. You can add languages there. For each language, Xcode will create a XIB for that language, so you only have to edit each XIB.

Comment: Yeah, the whole XIB. Maybe the localization step should be the last, when you have all UI setup.