# iOS is there a way to assign Localized String to a UILable from IB/storyboard

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistoryboard, iboutlet, nslocalizedstring

I want to assign `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)` to a UILabel from storyboard without creating an outlet for it.

Comment: May be this what you looking for: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401987/using-localized-text-in-uilabel-in-interface-builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401987/using-localized-text-in-uilabel-in-interface-builder) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just select your `storyboard/xib`, go to `File Inspector`. In the `Localization` part, you can tick the language you want. Then, it will create a `.string` file with all text used in `storyboard`. You'll just have to provide a translation for each text used in `storyboard`.

If no language appear in this part, you have to change values of `Localization native development region` in Info of your project.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create .strings files for my .xib,  but these files are empty, can you give an example how I can add translated text for my labels.

Comment: Have you got text in your xibs ? For each label or button (or whatever contains text), Xcode will automatically fill the .string file for you. Put some text on your xib, and restart the operation in `Localization` part (uncheck then check). It will refresh the .string file for you.

Comment: Replacing .strings files (uncheck and then check) worked!!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: so it's just an additional file? one for settings, second for code, third for storyboard?

Comment: @user25 Yes it's an additional .strings file. Usually, one per storyboard (or xib if you use them) and one for the strings included in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW4), the official Apple guide to translating storyboard texts. I found it pretty straightforward. I am currently translating texts in-code, in the storyboard and in my info.plist files without issue. Hope it helps!